# Matlab: Performing operations with 'struct' in image processing

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-struct

I have two images - one binarized, and one original.

I use the **binarized** image to segment using bwconncomp and then for every blob/region, I want to sum the pixel-intensities from the **original** image.

I do that by:

```
blobMeasurements = regionprops(binarizedImage, originalImage, 'pixelvalues');
```

Now, I have a struct with a 'p x 1' vector for each blob/region. I need to sum these  pixel intensities, such that I have one 'sum' value for each blob/region. How do I perform this operation? Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe using `sum`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
blobIntensities = arrayfun(@(x) sum(x.pixelvalues(:)), blobMeasurements);
```

`arrayfun` runs the given function `@(x) sum(x.pixelvalues(:))` on each of the `p`element of the structure array `blobMeasurements`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope:
>>>Undefined function 'sum' for input arguments of type 'struct'.
>>>Error in @(x)sum(x(:))